# Javascript merge and compose Objects with same ID

Tags: javascript, merge

I've been trying to merge data and get this result:

```
data = [{serviceID: 22, quantite: 120, typeConviveId: 6},
       {serviceID: 23, quantite: 240, typeConviveId: 6},
        {serviceID: 24, quantite: 100, typeConviveId: 7},
        {serviceID: 25, quantite: 150, typeConviveId: 7}]
```

what needed at end :

```
result: [ { "22": "120", "23": "240", "typeConviveId": "6"},
        { "24": "100", "25": "150", "typeConviveId": "7" } ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: do you need a general case function or those are the only fields that you will always have? (`serviceID`, `quantite`, and `typeConviveId`)

Comment: Family first connexo, maybe whe're not in the same meridian, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.reduce`, along with a list of unique `typeConviveId` deduped using a `Set` with `[...new Set(data.map(x=>x.typeConviveId))]`:

```js
const data = [{serviceID: 22, quantite: 120, typeConviveId: 6}, {serviceID: 23, quantite: 240, typeConviveId: 6}, {serviceID: 24, quantite: 100, typeConviveId: 7}, {serviceID: 25, quantite: 150, typeConviveId: 7}];

const result = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.typeConviveId))].map(
  id => data
  .filter(x => x.typeConviveId === id)
  .reduce((acc, val) => {
    return { ...acc,
      [val.serviceID]: '' + val.quantite
    }
  }, {
    typeConviveId: '' + id
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot connexo, it's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `reduce` & in the callback function use `findIndex` to get the object which has same `typeConviveId`. `findIndex` will return the index of the object which has same `findIndex` from the accumulator array which is represented by `acc`. In `fiindIndex` is -1 then create a new object with required keys and push it in the accumulator array. If there already exist an array with same `typeConviveId` then just update the object with new key

```js
let data = [{
    serviceID: 22,
    quantite: 120,
    typeConviveId: 6
  },
  {
    serviceID: 23,
    quantite: 240,
    typeConviveId: 6
  },
  {
    serviceID: 24,
    quantite: 100,
    typeConviveId: 7
  },
  {
    serviceID: 25,
    quantite: 150,
    typeConviveId: 7
  },
  {
    serviceID: 25,
    quantite: 250,
    typeConviveId: 7
  }
]


let newData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.typeConviveId === curr.typeConviveId;
  })
  if (findIndex === -1) {
    acc.push({
      typeConviveId: curr.typeConviveId,
      [curr.serviceID]: curr.quantite

    })

  } else {
    acc[findIndex][curr.serviceID] = curr.quantite

  }



  return acc;


}, []);

console.log(newData)
```

The expected result have a problem. If there is a duplicate key for example suppose if the key like `22` i s repeated , then it will have the last value.

```
{
        serviceID: 25,
        quantite: 150,
        typeConviveId: 7
      },
      {
        serviceID: 25,
        quantite: 250,
        typeConviveId: 7
      }
```

In this case `serviceID` in both object is 25, So its value will be 250. It will not have two keys with separate value

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer brk! There are no duplicated key, result is fine